# The handle is invalid is thrown when the method under test calls Console.CursorVisible

Tags: c#, console-application, xunit

I'm using Xunit to test a method that contains `Console.CursorVisible = false;`.  The following error is thrown when `Console.CursorVisible` is executed; am I missing something?

> System.IO.IOException: 'The handle is invalid.'

```cs
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        // Arrange
        var process = new Process();
    }
}

class Process
{
    public Process()
    {
        // Executes successfully:
        Console.WriteLine("test");

        // Throws the IOException: 'The handle is invalid.'
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
    }
}
```

### Update

Following the suggestion in the comments, I added the `xunit.runner.console` to the project as the following; however, that did not solve the issue.

```
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.console" Version="2.4.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
```

Comment: It fails when the process does not have a console.  Such as is commonly the case in a unit test.  Either delete the statement or use the xunit.runner.console package to get a console.

Comment: I guess adding a reference to the package `xunit.runner.console` is not sufficient, could you please provide an example of how the above test should be changed?

Comment: @HansPassant any thoughts?